# Should I define one subtype which is exactly the same as the supertype

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an java assignment. Its requirement shows that there is an super-type called Module. It has two sub-type class "Compulsory Module" and "Elective Module". The former one inherits all attributes of the super-class; the latter has one extra attribute called department name.

I consider that the Compulsory Module is the same as the Module. It is right when define one sub-class which is the same as the super-class. Every module instance must be either compulsory or elective. There are no other types of module. Should I define Module as abstract class because I don't want to confuse when deciding what class should be use in the real situation. Or someone can give me some cues.

Comment: Module is the super-type. Compulsory module extends Module but doesn't define its own methods. Elective module extends Module and it also has one specific method associated with it. No need to define Module as abstact class. Define module accordingly and extend the sub-classes as requested

Answer (score 0):

The question you should ask is:  **Is an** Elective Module a Compulsory Module?
If this is the case, than you can let Elective Module be the superclass of Compulsory Module.

**Polymorphism** in Java is translated into the relation  **"is a"**

(In your assignment it is clear that the Module class should be abstract. Because it has the same "behavior" as the Elective Module class.)

Comment: I mean Elective Module and Compulsory Module is the same level. I wander that The super class (Module) should be abstract class or not because  Module is same as the Compulsory Module.

Comment: Than you should ask the question: "Do there exist generic modules?".  Probably not, because like you said, Elective Modules have the same "behavior" as a Module.
So I would make it abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an answer in your question. Looks like you're required to have 3 classes even though CompulsoryModule has no additional attributes and only extends Module.

Module itself can be abstract or not. It depends on what you're trying to achieve. In certain cases it's impossible for you to define super class Module as a non abstract class.

For instance, if Module has a method that you don't know how to implement unless you work with CompulsoryModule or ElectiveModule, then you have to define that method as abstract and thus make the whole class abstract.

Additionally, making class abstract prevents anyone from creating an instance of that class and one will only be able to instantiate a subclass. Again, that's needed in cases when certain things are not fully defined in Module itself and require a specific subclass to make sense of superclass' code.